# Outputting to a file in an infinite loop (deliberately)

Tags: c++

Which is probably dangerous. Say, we make a program which does exactly that.

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n=1;
    ofstream outfile("hi.txt");
    cout << "Press any key to execute program.";
    getch();
    while (n>0)
    {
        outfile << "A";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If left unattended and running, **how dangerous can this be?**

Comment: It will fill your hard drive or crash when you reach some filesystem size limit, depending on what occurs first. See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits

Comment: It seems a question that have nothing to do with programming...

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca: Please don't answer in the comments section

Comment: @BoundaryImposition it felt weird voting to close the question and than providing an answer.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca So don't provide an answer. But you _did_, and doing it in the wrong place is double-bad!

Comment: I'll remember the next time I feel the itch, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on your definition of *dangerous*.

Eventually, `outfile<<"A"` will begin to silently fail (you don't check for success) when space is exhausted, and your program will just sit there consuming 100% of one of your CPU cores. It's not going to send you to prison or murder anyone, and if your computer was constructed properly it won't even start a fire. But you don't *want* to do this.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca: Hah

Comment: won't _operator<<_ throw an exception when it fails to write ?

Comment: @nefas: Not unless you ask it to.